# If needs on a SQL Server instance unexpectedly grow, how easy is it to scale in Azure?

Tags: azure

If I have a SQL Server instance in Azure, that has about 1.0 TB of data, if the need were to unexpectedly grow to 50 TB, how easy would it be to scale?  Does Azure have restrictive plans (e.g. you pay X amount for a 5 TB VM and it's hard to move past that) or is the disk size, etc., abstracted away so you are just paying for what you use and can scale infinitely without friction?

Hopefully this makes sense.  I just need to know details concerning how scaling is possible (and if it is difficult).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may have changed in a year, but when I did some scaling in early 2018 it was easy to start, just a click or two, but it took a bit longer than i expected to finish the scaling operation.  I don't know if database size has anything to do with it but my sizes were around 50gb and it would take an hour sometimes, maybe more.  But there was nothing blocking me from choosing much higher scales and the db would be fairly responsive during the operation.  This was scaling within the premium scales and scaling from premium to and from vcore.  They have a fair bit of info on scaling but the actual initiation is simple, usually just a slider or two.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/04/26/azure-sql-database-scalability/